# Any idea why my video file sizes are so heavy?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation, video-sequence-editor, file-format

im sure this has come up before but I couldn't seem to find an answer to it.

Basically, I want to render out a 1K, 1000 frame video while retaining the quality of the image. The problem is, the file size is crazy huge (about 4 GB). Now all I am doing is dropping the frames into the video editor and rendering out as a ".mov" and then I also tried using the ".avi" file format.

Oddly enough, I tested it and dropped a 90 MB video into Blender with the same settings and I was using and then rendered...the 90MB video went to about 3.8 GB.

I'm sure its just a setting or something, but I have hunted all through the manual and such to no avail.

All ideas are greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks!

Comment: the file size is directly related to the amount of compression and the desired datarate. Some codecs are more efficient than  others. MOV or AVI are just containers, use a codec like mpeg4 and play with the datarate until you find a decent size with a quality loss you can live with.

Comment: Thanks @cegaton. I already understand though what toy are talking about, but the ing is when I send the exact same piece or video though something like Nuke (using the same codec container), but it is way faster and the file size is significantly smaller.

Comment: You're using nuke and you don't know why the file size is so big? Suggest to learn the basics first...

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, in a native blender, you can set your movie output in a few formats for example now that you mention it, AVI. you can choose AVI raw or AVI jpeg, the raw one is a 0 compression value (raw format) and with jpeg, it uses a jpeg compression system 
but i dont know if you have tried this or not